# Diff content of two versions of a webpage

Tags: html, automated-tests

I'm looking for a way to feed an app two url's and have it spit-out the diffs. Ideally, I would like to have it pull the actual js/css/html files and diff those. However, I would settle for some way to just diff the rendered source. (This is in-lieu of me getting perceptual diffs working)I was about to begin writing something to crawl the source but was not sure of how to pull it say, into a buffer, to compare. I was also hoping there may be some exiting libraries out there that I am not finding?

Comment: Are you looking for a Javascript solution?

Comment: Javascript would work. Really looking for any solution that will work. I'm pretty familiar with javascript and could definitely pull that off.